# Next Greater Element - https://leetcode.com/problems/next-greater-node-in-linked-list/

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I did the question with the Brute force way. I used two loops and time efficiency was bad. Here is the code :-

```
    public int[] nextLargerNodes(ListNode head) {
    int len = 0;
    ListNode temp = head;
    while(temp != null) {
        len++;
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    int[] answer = new int[len];
    temp = head;
    int i = 0;
    while(temp.next != null) {
        ListNode nextGreat = temp.next;
        while(nextGreat != null) {
            if(nextGreat.val > temp.val) {
                answer[i] = nextGreat.val;
                i++;
                break;
            }
            else {
                nextGreat = nextGreat.next;
            }
        }

        if(nextGreat == null) {
            answer[i++] = 0;
        }

        temp = temp.next;
    }

    answer[i] = 0;
    return answer;
}
```

Then I found another solution that uses stacks to solve the problem, but the solution also uses two loops. The efficiency was much better for the 2nd solution, even though it's not O(n), since it has two loops. The code:-

```
public int[] nextLargerNodes(ListNode head) {
    ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ListNode node = head; node != null; node = node.next)
        A.add(node.val);
    int[] res = new int[A.size()];
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i) {
        while (!stack.isEmpty() && A.get(stack.peek()) < A.get(i))
            res[stack.pop()] = A.get(i);
        stack.push(i);
    }
    return res;
}
```

I want to know what makes the solution with stacks so much more efficient compared to the brute force way, despite both the solutions having two loops.

Comment: there is something wrong in the second solution also; instead of pushing I's value into stack we need to push i-th element from list, such as -- stack.push(A.get(i));

Answer (score 0):

The second solution is O(N), even though it has two loops.

Every iteration of the inner loop pops an item off the stack.  How many times can that happen?

Comment: Even though every iteration of the inner loop pops an item, the inner loop pretty often runs more than once for every iteration of the outer loop? Why do you say the solution is O(N)?

Comment: No it doesn't.  Each iteration of the outer loop pushes exactly 1 item.  Each iteration of the inner loop pops exactly one item.  You can't pop more items than you push.

Comment: Oh so as per my understanding, the inner loop is O(1) instead of O(n) I was assuming it to be, since there will be only one item to be popped out for each iteration of the outer for loop. Hence, the time complexity of the entire code is O(n), resulting from the outer for loop. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

So we have to convert the linked list to an arrays and pass those to stack. So here the  Space complexity O(1) which is better and Time complexity O(n) which is efficient in this respect.